# Docker for Windows 10 Home

Tags: docker, windows-10

So here's the thing, I'm trying to install Docker but I can't get Hyper-V because I have Windows 10 Home. Is there any solution to run Docker normally? Except using Windows Subsystem for Linux I don't like that option... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you like WSL? This is the best option to run Docker on Windows

Comment: I don't really like it, I'm not fan of Linux... I prefer using Docker normally on Windows. And I wanna find out if there are any other options except this one and buying Windows 10 Pro or similar versions.

Comment: Docker always uses Linux! So you have to have a Linux VM. And you will not see it because you will use Docker from PowerShell or CMD anyway. So go for this option if you can!

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - that's not true. Windows supports docker containers natively. It's not a great idea to use it because windows images start at around 2gb, but it is possible.

Comment: @JanTuđan - despite my comment above, if you want to use docker you *must* get into Linux. It is almost completely useless on Windows and at best it is completely pointless. Even in Azure, 99% of docker containers are Linux based and docker is probably the entire reason WSL exists.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I know but related to the question he wants to use Linux otherwise he wouldn't need Hyper-V

Comment: He could be trying to run docker in a VM -- afaik, only Windows Server supports native docker. Other versions of Docker (non Linux that is) require hyper-v for isolation.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't Windows containers not only supported in the Docker Enterprise version?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I have been told that it is possible to use Docker on Windows but I don't need to use it 100%, I just need that for a small project, just to demonstrate how to do with containers and use Kubernetes too.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - No, Docker Enterprise is a defunct scheduling framework that was in competition with k8s. Windows containers are available in Docker Desktop for Windows for free right now.

Comment: @JanTuđan - kubernetes (k8s) doesn't run on Windows - only linux. To configure that you need to use WSL afaik. You can still run windows containers on k8s workers, but the k8s control-plan has a hard linux requirement. Like I said earlier, you *must* get into Linux. Windows 10 Home supports WSL2 with no changes, so just do it.

Comment: Besides, GNU/Linux is *much* better than Windows. You should wipe Windows Home from your machine and install Ubuntu, then give it a couple of months and you'll be happy that you switched. GNU/Linux is *real* computing. Windows is a toy for secretaries and managers who don't know how to use computers.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer okay so there is no other option than using Linux in Virtual Machine or installing WSL, yeah I can see that Linux is being used by every good programmer so I will try to switch but not yet because I don't have budget, I'm still a student so I like to learn things.

Comment: GNU/Linux is free, so you do have the budget. You can't get away with a VM in windows, it has to be WSL version 2, which is also free. You'll probably want to install ubuntu in WSL, which, again, is free. Once you've installed wsl/ubuntu then install Docker Desktop for Windows, which is also free. That will give you docker and kubernetes, for free. Being a student is no reason to avoid this stuff -- it's all open-source

Answer (score 0):

You can download hyper-v on windows home edition using some scripts and it works
Follow steps shown in below link

https://beebom.com/install-hyper-v-on-windows-10-home/